# cron can't see systemctl --user services

Tags: cron, systemctl

I have a user cronjob I setup with:

```
$ crontab -e
*/5 * * * * systemctl --user is-active test.service >> ~/test.txt
```

But for some reason the service is always displayed as offline when executed with cron, but not when I manually execute:

```
systemctl --user is-active test.service
```

Is this some kind of permission issue or how could I otherwise test that a service is still running periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who have that same problem.

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) systemctl --user is-active test.service
```

is working.